# Elastic search - Searching for asset availibility

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

i was wondering if there would be a way to use elastic search to make a query that returns  only objects that are available in a certain date range? how to structure the data?

What i would need is to query a db giving the starting and ending date, and finding all objects that available in that period for the whole duration between start and end date?

```
{object-available:
{
{start:'01/01/2012', end:'03/02/2012'},
{start:'05/05/2012', end:'31/12/2012'}
}
```

And searching for object that is available between 01/01/2012 - 15/01/2012 should return this object, 
but searching for 01/03/2012 - 01/04/2012 should not return it.

Comment: Did you make any attempt that didn't work? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by storing availability ranges as [Nested Objects](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) and then using [Nested Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html) or [Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-filter.html) to check that both start and end date fall into the desired date range. You can perform this check using [Bool Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html) with two must clauses containing [Date Range Queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-query.html). For example:

```
# Delete old version to make sure new settings are applied
curl -XDELETE "localhost:9200/dates-test/"
echo
# Create a new index with proper mapping 
# See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/dates-test" -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {"type": "string"},
                "object-available": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties" : {
                        "end" : {
                            "type" : "date"
                        },
                        "start" : {
                            "type" : "date"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# Put some test data
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/dates-test/doc/1" -d '{
    "name": "Record 1",
    "object-available":[
        {"start":"2012-01-01", "end":"2012-02-03"},
        {"start":"2012-05-05", "end":"2012-12-31"}
    ]
}
'
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/dates-test/doc/2" -d '{
    "name": "Record 2",
    "object-available":[
        {"start":"2012-02-01", "end":"2012-04-20"},
        {"start":"2012-04-25", "end":"2012-11-30"}
    ]
}
'
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/dates-test/_refresh"
echo
echo Test for the range 2011-12-01 - 2012-02-05. Should find only 1st record 
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/dates-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "object-available",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "start": {
                                    "from": "2011-12-01",
                                    "to": "2012-02-05"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "end": {
                                    "from": "2011-12-01",
                                    "to": "2012-02-05"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
echo Test for the range 2012-01-20 - 2012-12-01. Should find only 2nd record 
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/dates-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "object-available",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "start": {
                                    "from": "2012-01-20",
                                    "to": "2012-12-01"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "end": {
                                    "from": "2012-01-20",
                                    "to": "2012-12-01"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
echo Test for the range 2012-04-01 - 2013-01-01. Should find both record 
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/dates-test/doc/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "object-available",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "start": {
                                    "from": "2012-04-01",
                                    "to": "2013-01-01"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "end": {
                                    "from": "2012-04-01",
                                    "to": "2013-01-01"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like that, but not sure how to realize this in practice, is it possible for you to provide me an example maybe?